# Selenium - The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium - The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
I am new to selenium, could any one please help on this?

```js
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\iedriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1#identifier");
    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
    username.sendKeys("selenium");
}
```

Selenium - 3.3.1
Java - 1.8
Eclispe - Indigo
Compiler - 1.7

Comment: Can you add some more information as below: 1. What is your objective? 2. What are you trying to achieve? 3. What have you tried still now, publish your code. 4. What worked for you? 5.Where are you stuck? 6. Provide sample HTML DOM.

Comment: Eclipse is not allowing to use function send keys

Comment: Try updating your ECLIPSE to higher version.

Comment: @SajithKumar Use Intellij, it's far better than Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code with Chrome Driver/Browser:

```
package demo;


import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class TestAnyURLMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gbw']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("ABC");
    }

}
```

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: You don't have to use implicit wait whenever you find an element, If you use once then it will be available to throughout your program, your driver object is set with that implicit wait. And your xpath is vulnerable, You could use this `//a[text()='Gmail']`

Comment: I agree. I just wanted to provide the OP a quick solution before ending my business for the day. Thanks.

Comment: You could leave the xpath if you don't want to change, but edit your paragraph to reflect the usage of implicit wait properly because OP get the wrong idea of usage of implicit wait.